# Determine whether propositions are logically equivalent

Tags: discrete-mathematics, propositional-calculus

I have two propositions $(\lnot p\land q) \lor ( p \land q)$  and  $p \leftrightarrow q$.
By using truth table, I found that they are not equal. But I have to find that without truth table and this is what i have solved so far.

$$p \leftrightarrow q = (p\rightarrow q) \land (q \rightarrow p) = (\lnot p \lor q) \land (\lnot q∨p)$$

I want to confirm my next step. Should I just apply DE Morgan's law and then state that they are not equal?

Comment: Why De  Morgan? Apply Distributivity.

Comment: Not sure how. Can you demonstrate?

Comment: But it is enough to check the truth table for bi-conditional: $p ↔ q \equiv (p \land q) \lor (\lnot p \land \lnot q)$

Comment: It might be even simplier to fold the first proposition with distributivity.

Answer (score 1):

We can applied distributivity here,

$(\lnot p \lor q) \land (\lnot q \lor p) = [(\lnot p \lor q) \land \lnot q] \lor [(\lnot p \lor q) \land p] \\ = [(\lnot p \land \lnot q) \lor (q \land\lnot q)] \lor [(\lnot p \land p)\lor (q \land p)] = (\lnot p \land \lnot q) \lor (q \land p)$

From here, it should be clear why this is not equivalent to the other proposition you gave.